# How to GROUP_CONCAT where there are null values in MYSQL will fields from LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

This is related to my previous example question submitted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442539/how-to-group-concat-where-there-are-null-values-in-mysql).
I have the following sql query :

```
SELECT 
listings.*,
region.REGION_ID,
#GROUP_CONCAT(region.REGION_ID) AS GROUP_IDs,
......
......
INNER JOIN schedule ON schedule.SCHEDULE_ID = listings.LISTING_SCHEDULE_ID 
LEFT JOIN listing_region ON listing_region.LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID = 
listings.LISTING_ID 
......
......
WHERE listings.LISTING_ID IN 
(SELECT LISTING_ID FROM listings WHERE ..........
```

The result is as follows :

[image: Raw data without GROUP_CONCAT]

I get multiple RegionIDs for the same ListingID and rest is null (expected) for non-existing records from LEFT join.

Now I need to group region_Ids for the same Listing ID.

So the only change I did was commenting out "region.REGION_ID" and enabled "GROUP_CONCAT(region.REGION_ID) AS GROUP_IDs,".

The result is as follows :

[image: Results with GROUP_CONCAT]

I do not understand why null rows are now dropped. I want them...!
What should I correct here?

Comment: Did you add a group by clause?

Comment: No, I did not. Adding GROUP BY shows only one null record for all the records that have null fields for region_ID.

Comment: @ forpas : I should have used "GROUP BY LISTING_ID" (I tried REGION_ID instead) here. DId not notice that until you raised it.  Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Fine if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The only change I was supposed to do to Add: GROUP BY ListingID to main filter clause.